# SQL Server UniqueIdentifier as FK

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to execute the following but its giving an error  of, I tried doing it with designer, same error saying data type, precision and length must be the same, even though they are

```
ALTER TABLE CustomerUsers
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerUsers_Users
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID)
REFERENCES Customers(UniqueID)
```

**Error thrown:**

> ```
> Msg 1769, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Foreign key 'fk_CustomerUsers_Users' references invalid column 'UniqueID' in referencing table 'CustomerUsers'.
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
> ```

Here is My Table Structure.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
[CustomerID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
[ContentLocation] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
[UniqueID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[CustomerID] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerUsers](
[CustomerUserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CustomerUniqueID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[UserID] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomerUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[CustomerUserID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerUsers]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CustomerUsers_AspNetUsers] FOREIGN KEY([UserID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CustomerUsers] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_CustomerUsers_AspNetUsers]
GO
```

Comment: Well CustomerUsers doesn't have a column named UniqueID. Did you mean to use CustomerUniqueID? Did you also consider calling it CustomerID in all locations? ID already implies that it is probably unique...

Answer (score 1):

There is no column with the name `CustomerID` in `CustomerUsers` just `CustomerUniqueID`
modify your query as below

```
ALTER TABLE CustomerUsers
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_CustomerUsers_Users
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerUniqueID)
REFERENCES Customers(UniqueID)
```

Query same as [@Drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/343495/drew)

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the following should do the trick (in the case that you're wanting to set up `CustomerUsers.CustomerUniqueID` as a FK)

```
ALTER TABLE customerusers 
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_customerusers_users FOREIGN KEY (customeruniqueid) 
  REFERENCES customers(uniqueid)
```

what I changed: inferred that error was related to column not existing, noticed that you had already created a column which looked like what you might have been trying to shoot for, added that

Comment: Suggestion for improvement of your answer: Explain *why* your revised code "should do the trick" instead of just posting it. As it is, we have to compare your revised code against to original just to see what you have changed, which might be a hint why the original wasn't working. Also, you don't explicitly say why you think the OP would want to set up `CustomerUniqueID`. It's obvious that his original FK column doesn't exist, but you're not actually saying that.